# Date field not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, group-by, aggregate

I am trying to calculate "Month to date" using three joined tables. It always gives me error "not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause" The date field is **S.BUS_DAT**
I tried many things but always get same error. Any advise
Here is the code I use

```
SELECT
-- Select from IM_IN
M.ITEM_NO,
M.DESCR,
N.QTY_ON_HND,
M.PRC_1,
N.LST_COST,
N.LST_RECV_DAT,

--Select from IM_ITEM
M.CATEG_COD,
M.ATTR_COD_1,
M.ITEM_VEND_NO,
M.ALT_1_UNIT,
M.ALT_1_NUMER,
M.LST_COST,
count (S.BUS_DAT) AS BUS_DAYS,

**sum (QTY_SOLD) OVER (PARTITION BY Month (S.BUS_DAT))as **MTD****


FROM
dbo.IM_INV N
INNER JOIN dbo.IM_ITEM M
ON
N.ITEM_NO = M.ITEM_NO

INNER JOIN 
dbo.PS_TKT_HIST_LIN S
ON
N.ITEM_NO  = S.ITEM_NO


Group by
M.ITEM_NO,
M.DESCR,
M.ITEM_VEND_NO,
M.CATEG_COD,
M.ATTR_COD_1,
N.QTY_ON_HND,
N.LST_COST,
N.LST_RECV_DAT,
N.LST_SAL_DAT,
M.ALT_1_UNIT,
M.ALT_1_NUMER,
M.PRC_1,
M.LST_COST





Order by M.ITEM_NO
```

Comment: I can't read your question.  Therefore, I can't help you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen great comment. You should given a prize for that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen why can't you read this question, if not read that you are not supposed to comment. no one asking you for ans or forcing you to comment

Answer (score 0):

try to include `Month(S.BUS_DAT)` into `group by` as well:

```
SELECT
M.ITEM_NO, 
M.DESCR, 
N.QTY_ON_HND, 
M.PRC_1, 
N.LST_COST, 
N.LST_RECV_DAT, 
M.CATEG_COD, 
M.ATTR_COD_1, 
M.ITEM_VEND_NO, 
M.ALT_1_UNIT, 
M.ALT_1_NUMER, 
M.LST_COST, 
COUNT(S.BUS_DAT) AS BUS_DAYS, 
SUM(QTY_SOLD) OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH(S.BUS_DAT)) AS MTD
FROM dbo.IM_INV N
     INNER JOIN dbo.IM_ITEM M ON N.ITEM_NO = M.ITEM_NO
     INNER JOIN dbo.PS_TKT_HIST_LIN S ON N.ITEM_NO = S.ITEM_NO
GROUP BY M.ITEM_NO, 
         M.DESCR, 
         M.ITEM_VEND_NO, 
         M.CATEG_COD, 
         M.ATTR_COD_1, 
         N.QTY_ON_HND, 
         N.LST_COST, 
         N.LST_RECV_DAT, 
         N.LST_SAL_DAT, 
         M.ALT_1_UNIT, 
         M.ALT_1_NUMER, 
         M.PRC_1, 
         M.LST_COST, 
         MONTH(S.BUS_DAT)
ORDER BY M.ITEM_NO;
```

Comment: Thank you satishcse. It gives same error but for QTY_SOLD the error message "Column 'dbo.PS_TKT_HIST_LIN.QTY_SOLD' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." When I added S. QTY_SOLD to Group By I got this error "Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause."

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
sum(sum(QTY_SOLD)) OVER (PARTITION BY Month(S.BUS_DAT)) as MTD
```

Note:  You will still need `month(s.bus_dat)` in the `group by` clause.

If you only want the sum for the current month, then you don't want a window function, just conditional aggregation:

```
sum(case when year(s.bus_dat) = year(getdate()) and month(s.bus_dat) = month(getdate())
         then qty_sold
    end) as mtd
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon Linoff. The second code worked perfectly. The first code worked but item repeated. I so much appreciate it

Comment: Could you also please how to make LAST MONTH TO DATE from the second code?